# Python natural sort list of tuples (card game)

Tags: python, python-2.7, sorting, tuples

I am developing a text based game of Go Fish as a way of practicing/learning python. I want to sort the cards in the players hand for readability and am running into issues.

```
my_hand = [('3', 'Spades'), ('Ace', 'Hearts'), ('10', 'Clubs'), ('King', 'Diamonds'), ('4', 'Clubs')]
```

if I do:

```
my_hand.sort()
```

I get:

```
[('10', 'Clubs'), ('3', 'Spades'), ('4', 'Clubs'), ('Ace', 'Hearts'), ('King', 'Diamonds')]
```

I don't want the 10 to come first. But because I have 'Ace', 'King' 'Queen' 'Jack' as card values I can't sort as an int.

this is what I came up with. But I'm thinking there has to be a better way to do it, and the goal of this project is to learn new methods so I thouhgt I'd ask.

my solution:

```
def natural_sort(hand):
    number_cards = []
    ten_cards = []
    face_cards = []
    new_hand = []
    for card in hand:
        try:
            int(card[0])
            if card[0] != 10:
                number_cards.append(card)
            elif card[0] == 10:
                ten_cards.append(card)
        except ValueError:
            face_cards.append(card)
    number_cards.sort()
    face_cards.sort()
    new_hand.extend(number_cards)
    new_hand.extend(ten_cards)
    new_hand.extend(face_cards)
    return new_hand
```

Thoughts?

Comment: How exactly do you want to sort the cards? Could you be a bit more specific? Also, could you give an example of some expected output.

Comment: `hand.sort(key=lambda t: ['2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', 'Jack', 'Queen', 'King', 'Ace'].index(t[0]))`

Comment: Give your cards a lookup table with int values and sort by their values.  A dictionary like {'Ace' : 14, 'King' : 13, 'Queen': 12....'2': 2}, then use the current card as an key and sort by the value.

Comment: even though you cast `card[0]` to `int` in the `try` block: `int(card[0])`, the next line `if card[0] != 10:` will always be `True` because `card[0]` is still a `<str>` and you didn't save the cast

Comment: `my_hand.sort(key = lambda card: dict([(str(i), i) for i in range(2, 11)] + list(zip(('Jack', 'Queen', 'King', 'Ace'), range(11, 15))))[card[0]])`. You should write a proper sort helper function, and pass it as argument to `key`.

Comment: Thank you so much for your responses. I did not know a custom key could be set. I am going to try that!

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is assign a number value to your cards, as there are only 4 face cards. For example, say Ace=1, Jack=11, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

This is a nice use-case for a custom comparator! A comparator is a function used by a sorting algorithm to compare two items. cmp(a, b) returns -1 if a < b, 0 if a == b, and 1 if a > b.

To get the sort you want, you could do:

```
hand = [('10', 'Clubs'), ('3', 'Spades'), ('4', 'Clubs'), ('Ace', 'Hearts'), ('King', 'Diamonds')]

def card_cmp(card1, card2):
    try:
        c1num = int(card1[0])
    except ValueError:
        c1num = False

    try:
        c2num = int(card2[0])
    except ValueError:
        c2num = False

    if c1num and c2num:
        return cmp(c1num, c2num)
    elif c1num:
        return -1
    elif c2num:
        return 1
    else:
        return cmp(card1[0], card2[0])

print sorted(hand, cmp=card_cmp)
```

If you also want to sort the face cards by value rather than alphabetically, you'd have to encode that order somewhere, maybe with a dictionary like

```
face_cards = { 
  'Jack' : 11,
  'Queen' : 12,
  'King' : 13,
  'Ace' : 14,
}
```

and then your comparator could just be

```
def card_cmp(card1, card2):
    try:
        c1num = int(card1[0])
    except ValueError:
        c1num = face_cards[card1[0]]

    try:
        c2num = int(card2[0])
    except ValueError:
        c2num = face_cards[card2[0]]

    return cmp(c1num, c2num)
```